# How to filter year in DateFormat for the current year?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a `TimeSeriesChart` with a specific `DateTimeTickFormatterSpec` that formats dates in the current year as `MMM` and everything else as `yMMM`. In other words, the month should always be shown and the year should only be shown if it's not the current year.

```
01-01-2020 => Jan 2020
12-01-2021 => Dec 2021
01-01-2022 => Jan
```

I'm currently looking at `charts.BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec.fromNumberFormat()` which takes in a `DateFormat` for formatting the chart's ticks. Addressing the `DateFormat` for this case appears to be the simplest approach to me.

I wanted to ask if anyone knew if a conditional `DateFormat` is achievable or if anyone had any insight on using `DateTimeFormatterFunction` to achieve the above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NVM, figured it out.

You'll want to use `charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec` and specify a function along with your 2 `DateFormats`. In my case, `currentYear` contains `MMM` and `previousYear` contains `yMMM`.

```
    tickFormatterSpec: charts.BasicDateTimeTickFormatterSpec((date) =>
            date.year == DateTime.now().year
                ? currentYear.dateTickFormatter!.format(date)
                : previousYear.dateTickFormatter!.format(date))
```